# Inkscape: Can not get "Pattern Along Path" feature to work as I need it

Tags: inkscape, path, patterns

I am using Inkscape's "Pattern Along Path" feature.  And I think I am having problem because Inkscape is rotating my pattern 90 degrees from the orientation I would prefer.

I've a "path":

```
.
 .
  .
 .
.
 .
```

And a pattern:

```
ooo
```

And want to get this:

```
ooo
 ooo
  ooo
 ooo
ooo
 ooo
```

But I keep getting this:

```
o
 o
  o
 o
o
 o
```

Is there a way to force the "Pattern Along Path" feature change (rotate) how it draws the pattern onto the path?

Added later...

This is a snap shot of the image I am working on next to the "Pattern Along Path" dialog:

[image]

To place the "O" pattern onto the line on the left, I click on the past icon (clip-board with paper, 3rd from the left under "Pattern source"). If I click on "Pattern is vertical" before applying the "O" pattern, the selected line on the left disappears.  If I click on "Pattern is vertical" again, the line is restored.  If I click on "Pattern is vertical" again, then click on the past icon, then click on "Pattern is vertical" again, the line is restored but looks just as above (the "O" pattern only 1 wide along the length of the line).

This is Inkscape 0.91 running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Inkskape there are **two different plugins** to be used to put a pattern along a path:

- [Pattern Along Path Live effect](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html): *Path... Path Effects... +... Pattern Along Path*, to be applied as a Path Effect:

[image: Live effect]

- [Pattern Along Path Extension](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-GenerateFromPath.html): *Extensions... Generate from Path... Pattern along Path*

[image: Extension]

The plugins are slightly different. In this case I suggest you to use the **Extension** and select "**Pattern is vertical**" and "**Duplicate the pattern before deformation**" option.

Snake deformation type:

[image: Snake deformation]

Ribbon deformation type:

[image: Ribbon deformation]

Comment: I can not duplicate your answer. My "Pattern along Path" menu does not look like yours.  I'm running 0.91 which is what is advertised as the current stable version on the inkscape.org web site.

Comment: I'm running 0.91 too. Can you post a screenshot of path, pattern, dialog and result (as in my example)? And can you post your svg file too?

Comment: Apparently there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1428267) in the "Pattern along Path" in Inkscape 0.91 identified and solved last year and put into 0.91 r13771.  However, there appears to be a lot of 0.91 version of Inkscape floating around.  Which is a little confusing!  I just checked an up-to-date Fedora Linux box and the "Pattern along Path" is even more broken than the Ubuntu Linux box.  The Fedora box is running Inkscape 0.91 r13725. Turns out, the Ubuntu box is also running Inkscape 0.91 r13725.  What are you running?

Comment: Just verified I also have Inkscape 0.91 r13725 running on my Windows 10 computer.  I re-downloaded the Inkscape Windows installer and did a binary compare with the previously downloaded Inkscape Windows installer and they match.  When I run the installer, I only got the "change", "repair" & "uninstall" options.  No "install" option. Worst of all, when I run the Windows version of Inkscape, I still can not duplicate your answer.

Comment: The version I've used is 0.91 r13725 on Windows 10 too. But I used a different way to put the pattern along the path: **Extensions... Generate from Path... Pattern along Path** (I've updated my answer). The parameters are a bit different respect the *Path effect* and the effect is a bit different too: try this.

Comment: Solved!  Thank you.  Using Extensions->Generate From Path->Pattern Along Path works as expected.  Why on earth does the other even exist?